# ODE standard form.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I noticed that whenever mathematicians talk about Legendre polynomials they bring the ODE to the form $(1-x^2)f''(x)-2xf'(x)+n(n+1)f(x)=0$. When solving Poisson's equation, this form is not the most intuitive one, because you only get this one after substituting $x=\cos(t)$. My question is: Is there a reason Mathematicians always tend to have an ODE in a particular form and if yes: What determines this standard form?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever mathematicians talk about Legendre polynomials they bring the ODE to the form

... in which its solutions are **polynomials**. Quite a natural thing to do. Yes, the polynomials are of most interest on $[-1,1]$ and yes, the composition $P_n(\cos t)$ is what comes up from separating the 3D Laplacian in coordinates. But the algebraic polynomials are considered the simplest, most basic of all functions. At least I find $\frac12(3x^2-1)$ easier to think about than $\frac12(3\cos^2t-1)$.

Legendre polynomials have important orthogonality relation $\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx =0 $ ($m\ne n$) which becomes something a bit more complicated if you plug in $x=\cos t$. This orthogonality is useful for polynomial approximation in $L^2[-1,1]$. 
And the  solutions of $P_n(x)=0$  are the sample points of Gauss-Legendre quadrature, a widely used numerical integration algorithm.

These are reasons to look at Legendre polynomials as *algebraic* polynomials, not  as  trigonometric ones.